# Storing Credentials used to Run PowerShell as Administrator

Tags: credentials, powershell-4.0, elevated-privileges

**My goal:**
To Run PowerShell as an Administrator, which requires admin authentication in our environment, and to store those credentials in a variable to be used by the script run in that session.

**In case that's not enough info:**
I am writing a script which uses the username of the admin running the script in a variable (for logging).
I don't want to make the admins who will run this script have to log in twice. Our environment is set up so when one runs Powershell as Administrator he is prompted for admin credentials. I don't want to have the script prompt for credentials a second time to store them in variable.
$env:USERNAME doesn't help me because I don't want the username logged into the computer, I want the admin username used to run the script.

How can I accomplish this?

The closest I've come so far is running the following in standard PowerShell session:

```
$AdminCred = Get-Credential
Start-Process powershell -Credential $AdminCred -ArgumentList "-file c:\ScriptName.ps1"
```

...but that leaves me with two problems:

1) Im running PS with Admin rights, but it not the same as "Running as Administrator" in that my

```
#Requires -RunAsAdministrator
```

line rejects it. and

2) This opens a new PS window and my $AdminCred variable is not stored there.

Seems relatively simple, but I'm still pretty new at this PS game.
Really appreciate whatever help I can get...

Answer (score 0):

First you store password as secure string and store username and password in one variable using system.management.automation after pass that variable to authenticate